# CSS-only solution for embedded facebook videos

Tags: html, facebook, css, video

My site/CMS embeds youtube and facebook videos - [we made them and post those there], along with written posts. Until recently, both facebook and youtube videos had 16:9 dimensions. We would embed a player inside a div with a height of zero and do vertical padding of 56.25%; - a standard "trick" that lots of sites use.

```
.video__embed {
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
  position: relative;
}
```

Now, facebook also allows posting videos with other dimensions. To play those, I temporarily used height 100% and hiding overflow on the FB PLAYER div. It clips the video - bad solution. We only have the video url. Hence, no way to know the dimensions before the clip is embedded.

Spent a couple of hours trying to come-up with a CSS-only solution. Calc does not seem to be enough. Any ideas how to calculate say padding-left [and maybe /-right], so I could present those not 16:9 clips inside the wide player, much like HDTV plays older movies?

Trying hard to avoid having to resort to JavaScript, but until now could not come-up with a way to do with this CSS-only. One thing that comes to mind is flexbox, but maybe because I don't know how to use that... :)

Thank you

Comment: How would calc or flexbox help you, if you don’t know the actual video aspect ratio? You can not adapt element dimensions to values you don’t even know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did a bit of digging.

1. there is an API - oEmbed at http://oembed.com/, which could be used from the backend to determine the video dimensions. facebook, youtube and many other resources support it. long term, using oEmbed on the backend, when possible, is probably the best.
2. once we know the dimensions, margin: 0 auto; can be used to center the embeds.

my backend does not, at this time, retrieve the dimensions. hence, my "default" css clips video, then JavaScript adjusts the padding, and optionally width. this solution is clearly inferior to having backend provide the dimensions [just the ratio], for many applications, including my site done with Django/Backbone. With ratio available on the backend, we could print ready HTML. For react or angular, it probably does not make that much of a difference.

On related subject, it is a bit strange how facebook overrides embed sizes, making adjusting those more difficult. Does not seem fully worked out, in conjunction with variable width:height ratio.